# Retrieving multiple items sequentially from chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm writing an interface for user settings in a Chrome extension. Here's how I define the settings:

```
function Setting(label, type, defaultData) {
    this.label = label;
    this.type = 'checkbox';
    this.defaultData = defaultData;
}

var Settings = {};
Settings['setting-one'] = new Setting('Setting one', 'checkbox', 'true');
Settings['setting-two'] = new Setting('Setting two', 'checkbox', 'true');
```

Here's how I set the default value for each setting:

```
function setDefaultSetting(setting, defaultValue) {
    chrome.storage.sync.get(setting, function(results) {
        if (!results[setting]) {
            // If the setting has not yet been defined, define it now
            var dataToSave = {};
            dataToSave[setting] = defaultValue;
            chrome.storage.sync.set(dataToSave, function() {
                debugMsg('set `' + setting + '` to ' + defaultValue);
            });
        }
    });
}

for (var setting in Settings) {
    if (Settings.hasOwnProperty(setting)) {
        var s = Settings[setting];
        if (s.type == 'checkbox') {
            setDefaultSetting(setting, s.defaultData);
        }
    }
}
```

So far, so good. Now I want to print the list of settings as checkboxes. Here's what I've tried:

```
function printSettingsModal() {
    var output += '<form>';
    for (var setting in Settings) {
        if (Settings.hasOwnProperty(setting)) {
            var s = Settings[setting];
            if (s.type == 'checkbox') {
                chrome.storage.sync.get(setting, function(results) {
                    output += '<p><input id="setting-' + setting + '" type="checkbox"';
                    if (results[setting] == 'true') { output += ' checked="checked"'; }
                    output += '><label for="setting-' + setting + '">' + s.name + '</label></p>';
                });
            }
        }
    }
    output += '</form>';
    return output;
}
```

This doesn't work because `chrome.storage.sync.get()` is asynchronous. How can I loop through my array of settings and retrieve the associated `chrome.storage` data for each setting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't actually have to do that sequentially, or even set defaults explicitly beforehand.

`chrome.storage.local.get` has 3 forms for its first argument:

- `"key"` (string): retrieves just one key, as you're doing
- `["key1", "key2"]` (array): retrieves all the values for keys in the array
- `{ key1: default1, key2: default2 }` (dictionary object): retrieves all the values for keys specified, returning the provided default value if it's not in storage

You can collect all the settings you want to retrieve and get them in one operation.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do it is to use a **recursive function**, add each option inside the callback of the `chrome.storage.sync.get()` method, and call the `printSettingsModal()` function increasing the index. To do this **you'll need an array structure to at least store the name of the settings so you can iterate over it**, you can edit your `Settings` object and add the method `add()` that will do this for you. You can then call the `chrome.storage.sync.get()` method recursively and call a `callback` when finished.

**So, first, here is your new `Settings` object:**

```
function Setting(label, type, defaultData) {
    this.label = label;
    this.type = 'checkbox';
    this.defaultData = defaultData;
}

function Settings() {
    var _this = this;

    this.list = [];
    this.add = function(key, obj) {
        this.list.push(key);
        _this[key] = obj;
    }
}

var mySettings = new Settings();

mySettings.add('setting-one', new Setting('Setting one', 'checkbox', 'true'));
mySettings.add('setting-two', new Setting('Setting two', 'checkbox', 'true'));
```

**Now you will have something like this:**

```
console.log(mySettings);
Settings {list: Array[2], add: function, setting-one: Setting, setting-two: Setting}
```

**Here comes the recursive function, you will need to:**

1. Initialize the output as `"<form>"` at the beginning.
2. Add all the settings in the intermediate steps.
3. Finalize the output adding `"</form>"` at the end.
4. Call a callback with the output so you can use it properly.

Here is an example of what your function will look like using recursion:

```
function printSettingsModal(index, output, callback) {
    var s = mySettings[mySettings.list[index]];

    if (index === 0) {
        // first element is going to be created
        output = "<form>";
    } else if (index > mySettings.list.length-1) {
        // the last setting has been added
        // call the callback
        callback(options);
    }

    if (s.type == 'checkbox') {
        chrome.storage.sync.get(setting, function(results) {
            output += '<p><input id="setting-' + setting + '" type="checkbox"';
            if (results[setting] == 'true') { output += ' checked="checked"'; }
            output += '><label for="setting-' + setting + '">' + s.name + '</label></p>';
        if (index === mySettings.list.length-1) {
            // last element has been created
            output += '</form>';
            printSettingsModal(++index, output, callback);
        }
        });
    }
}
```

**Now you just need to define a callback and call it:**

```
function myCallback(options) {
    // do something with the option string
    // like:
    document.getElementById('form-container').innerHTML = options;
}

printSettingsModal(0, null, myCallback);
```

If I wrote all correctly, this will work for you. Hope it helped.